# Magento: Can I load a cart by quoteId?

Tags: magento, load, checkout, cart

I need to load a cart by a quoteId, cause I want to add a product to a different cart than the current cart. Is this possible?
TIA!

Answer (score 2):

```
$cartId = 99;
$cart = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($cartId);
$productId = 55;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId());
$cart->addProduct($product);
```

Comment: I found this: `$quote = $this->_getModel('sales/quote')->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteId);
            $cart = $this->_getModel('comprasecundaria/cart')->setQuote($quote)->getQuote();` ... I'm working on it...

Comment: Marius I am doing same but in cart price and subtotal showing null. Do you have any idea whey they are not showing. if use(checkout/cart) then they show.

Comment: Sorry. I have no idea.

Comment: @Pushpendra i am getting 0 as well for subtotal where in db it has right value. Did you find anything wrong?